# How to calculate the number of documents a term occurs in using python?

Tags: python, tf-idf

I'm trying to calculate IDF values for TF-IDF vectorization. I'm trying to calculate number of documents that contain each unique word of the vocab.

This is the corpus:

corpus = ['this is the first document',
          'this document is the second document',
          'and this is the third one',
          'is this the first document']

my code:

...

## IDF values:

```
for i in range(0,len(corpus)):
    o=corpus[i].split(' ')
    c=0
    for wor in n:
        for k in range(0,len(corpus)):
            if wor in o[k]:
            c=c+1
        print(wor, c)
```

...

Output i'm getting:
and 0
document 0
first 1
is 3
one 3
second 3
the 4
third 4
this 5
and 0
document 1
first 1
is 3
one 3
second 3
the 4
third 4
this 5
and 1
document 1
first 1
is 3
one 3
second 3
the 4
third 4
this 5
and 0
document 0
first 1
is 3
one 3
second 3
the 4
third 4
this 5

The output i need:
this 4
is 4
the 4
first 2
document 3
second 1
and 1
third 1
one 1

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `n` contains your vocabulary. Then you can do this:

```
wordsets = [ frozenset(document.split(' ')) for document in corpus ]
results = []
for word in n:
    count = sum( 1 for s in wordsets if word in s )
    results.append((count, word))
for count, word in sorted(results, reverse=True):
    print(word, count)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. however, what you are trying to calculate is not IDF. It's just the frequency of the particular word in all documents.

```
 for i in range(0,len(corpus)):
   words=corpus[i].split(' ')
   for word in words:
     if word in freq:
       freq[word] = freq[word] + 1
     else:
       freq[word] = 1
 print(freq)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is perfect for the `Counter` class from the `collections` package

```
from collections import Counter

words = ' '.join(corpus)
output = Counter(words.split()).most_common()
```

Comment: A very nice solution, to a very different problem.